# Flutter: How to apply TweenAnimation to multiple properties of Transform?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using Transform to move and scale a container.

```
Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(20, 20, 0.0)
                ..scale(0.9, 1.0, 1.0),
    child: _buildContainer(customColor),
)
```

I can use TweenAnimationBuilder builder to add animation to either transate or scale like this:

```
TweenAnimationBuilder(
    tween: Tween<Double>(begin: 0, end: 20),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    builder: (_, double translateVal, __) {
        return Transform(
            translate: Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(translateVal, translateVal, 0.0)
                ..scale(0.9, 1.0, 1.0),
            child: _buildContainer(customColor),
        );
    }
)
```

The above code works and I can similarly add it to scale but only by removing animation from translate. How to add animation to both translate and scale together? As the tween argument of TweenAnimationBuilder only takes a single begin and end value and not a list of different begin and end values which I can then assign to different properties of transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, to add multiple animations, we can use what is known as [Staggered Animation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations). I created 2 tweens for 2 properties - translate and scale and the animation is then controlled by AnimationController.

Using Staggered Animation, multiple animations on a single element like a container is possible at the same time or sequentially.